# Other than people, what "reliable" and trustworthy search engine should we optimize for?

Tags: search-engines

I have looked at this question: [Other than Google, how do I decide which search engines to optimize for?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/405/other-than-google-how-do-i-decide-which-search-engines-to-optimize-for) but it doesn't match what I will ask.

When I made my website, I make it primarily for people then search engines. A large number of us see Google as king of search engines, but lately it hasn't been serving people well both in adsense and search results.

From personal experience, Adsense paid me a large chunk of money several years back and I'm sure it has happened to others too where they received a large chunk back in the day, and now they receive very little if any money.

But lately when I browse the web looking for specific material (especially on mobile), Google has failed on many occasions and decides to make its own assumptions on the queries I really want it to search for. If I make the same query in duckduckgo.com search engine, I get more meaningful results including results from websites that google doesn't even list in its results.

This makes me think that Google is being shady lately.

Now that I ranted, what I want to do now is focus on delivering the best experience to the people without the search engines manipulating guest's queries (by hiding relevant results and/or changing the query in the background).

Other than Google, what search engine should I be trusting the most? and if that isn't known by the community then what search engine would the highest number of professionals use (other than google)? That way I'll have a starting point.

Comment: Have you tried Google's "verbatim" search mode?   My problem with Google search these days is that it ignores half your query most of the time.   The verbatim mode makes Google act more like it used to for me.  I install this as my default search engine to make my browser use that mode: http://ready.to/search/en/?sna=GV30&prf=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Ftbs%3Dli%3A1%26amp%3Bnum%3D30%26amp%3Bq%3D&des=Google%20Verbatim%20%2830%20results%20per%20page%29&in=utf&ou=ono&mod=pn

Comment: As for AdSense, I too have observed a steep decline in RPMs in the last few years.   Not all of that is Google's fault (although Google is taking a larger slice of the pie than they used to.)  Part of it is an increase in international traffic.   Advertisers are willing to pay far less for traffic not from the US.   Especially less for countries like India where English sites are often getting tons of visitors now.   Mobile is also killing RPMs because of the stunted ability of phones compared to desktop.   You can't show as many ads, and advertisers won't pay as much on mobile.

Comment: I've closed this as off-topic because you are asking for recommendations.  Note that the question you linked to is very subtly NOT asking for recommendations.  It is asking how you should "decide".   The answers focus on which stats to look at and how to be search engine agnostic.